# How would I join these tables via SQL?

Tags: sql

```
Table1Orders
   OrderID(pk)
   ISBN(fk)
   ProductID(fk)
   OrderDate
   Total

Table2Books
   ISBN(pk)
   AuthorID(fk)
   PublisherID(fk)
   Title
   PubDate

Table3Authors
   AuthorID(pk)
   AuthorName
   AuthorAddress
   AuthorPhone

Table4Publishers
   PublisherID(pk)
   PublisherName
   PubAddress
   PubPhone
```

How would I find which Publisher has sold the most books?

Would I need an `INNER JOIN` between `Orders` and `Book` details?

How would I sort the returned data so it relates the `publisher` to the `ISBN` and most sold?

Comment: Do you mean which publisher had the most revenue? I ask because I don't see a Quantity field on any table that would show how many books were sold. I would presume Total is a dollar amount.

Comment: `select PublisherID,count(*) from Orders,Books group by PublisherID where Orders.publisherID = Books.publisherID` will give you all publishers and their quantity sold.You can then use this query as inner query and fetch the publisherID with maximmum count.

Comment: @GauravSehgal Orders doesn't have a publisherID and your `where` clause is after your `group by` clause

Comment: @EoinS Thanks for pointing out.This should work, right? `select PublisherID,count(*) from Orders,Books where Orders.ISBN = Books.ISBN group by PublisherID`

Comment: Is this your homework? I think I had the same question back in my first year as developer...

Comment: @GauravSehgal nailed it

Comment: @GauravSehgal thanks for the help. Do you think it would be more simple if I add a quantity column to the orders table?

Comment: @Heljos No because a) `orders` should just have `orders` information b) You cannot relate quantity in `orders` table c) you should not add information into tables just to make your querying simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Based on column names if you join orders to books and books to publishers to get a publisher to orders link as a table, then query that by publisher, group by publisher and count the number of rows:

```
select p.PublisherName, count(*) as BooksSold
from Table1Orders o 
inner join Table2Books b on o.ISBN = b.ISBN
inner join Table4Publishers p on b.PublisherID = p.PublisherID
group by p.PublisherName
order by count(*) desc
```

[Here is a sample with explicit and implicit joins](http://rextester.com/RSO40696)